# Determination of Adjoint Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator

> Given energy eigenstates $|n\rangle$ and an annihilation operator $$A|n\rangle:=a_n|n-1\rangle$$ with $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$, how does one determine the adjoint $A^\dagger$?

By definition of the adjoint operator 
$$\langle A^\dagger m|n\rangle=\langle m|An\rangle=a_n\langle m|n-1\rangle$$ holds, orthonormality of energy eigenstates $\langle m|n\rangle=\delta_{m,n}$ further yields 
$$\langle A^\dagger m|n\rangle=a_n \delta_{m,n-1}= a_{m+1} \delta_{m+1,n}= a_{m+1}\langle m+1|n\rangle$$
 and thus 
$$\langle A^\dagger m|= a_{m+1}\langle m+1|.$$
 So now I know how $A^\dagger$ acts on an eigenket from the left after turning the result into a bra. How do I retrieve the action on the ket? I got very confused here.

Comment: Can you absorb the phases of the *a* s into the recursive definitions of the bras to make the *a*s real? Then taking adjoints of real brackets would take you there.